# Restructure json arrays created by a while loop in php, fetching values from a database

Tags: php, arrays, json, while-loop

I am getting two JSON arrays that I need merged each time a while loop runs a fetch from my database. This is the structure array result I am getting as of now:

```
{id=1,cid=1,fname=Lorna,vorname=King,gender=female,dob=1985,company=helsana,monthly_amount=150},
{id=2,cid=1,fname=Brian,vorname=King,gender=male,dob=2007,company=helsana,monthly_amount=100}
```

I need it to look like this:

```
{ 1={id:1, cid:1 fname=Lorna, vorname:King, gender:female, dob:1985, company:helsana, monthly_amount:100}, 2={id:2, cid:1 fname=Brian, vorname:King, gender:male, dob:2005, company:helsana, monthly_amount:150} }
```

To make it easier to pick values from the array.
Here is the PHP code that I am using:

```
<?php
include_once "conn.php";
$show= $mysqli->query("SELECT id,cid,fname,vorname,gender,dob,company,monthly_amount FROM family where cid = '1' ");
$arr = array();
while($row = $show->fetch_assoc()){
    $arr[] = $row;
}
$json_response = json_encode($arr, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP);
echo $str = substr($json_response, 1,-1);
?>
```

Am kinda new to this please someone help me out.

Comment: What are you using `substr` for? And please show the actual json output you are getting, because the example you show is not correct - its not valid json and it would not be produced from the php code you are showing

Comment: Lastly show how you are trying to use the resulting json, because i expect your current format is easily consumed

Answer (score 0):

You can just force it when you make the array in PHP:

```php
$arr = array();
$index = 1; // Start the index where you want the count
while($row = $show->fetch_assoc()){
    $arr[$index++] = $row;
}
```

Or, if you want it to match the id of the row:

```
$arr = array();
while($row = $show->fetch_assoc()){
    $arr[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```